# Unable to provision API App on Linux App Service Plan hosted in ASE

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-api-apps, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

Unable to provision API App on Linux App Service Plan hosted in ASE. Is there any constrain or limitations.

When i create API APP Windows app service plans are showing up but not Linux app service plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue in the portal, looks Linux service plan hosted in ASE v1 not support API App, just Windows plan supports it.

[image]

[image]